# facebook application tabs & realtime update question

Tags: facebook, user-interface, tabs, facebook-graph-api

1.i see in the developer page app config a section named "Page Tabs" , what is it for? 
2. anyone has example of facebook graph "Real-time Updates" in php?

Comment: Please ask questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

"Page Tabs" are applications which appear under their own tab heading and can be added to fan pages. At present they can only be built using FBML, but are schedled to switch to an iframe implementation this quarter.

Further info - http://www.facebook.com/notes/pop-art-inc/the-state-of-facebook-tab-applications/442661413507